# VBA IRibbonUI.Invalidate causes Excel to crash when used too many times

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

At the moment I'm working on an Excel document which uses several Add-ins. These Add-ins contain functions that I'm planning on using in other workbooks. One group of functions takes care of some functions for a custom made ribbon:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (destination As Any, source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
Private Const ribbonXMLAddress As String = "RibbonSaveLocation"
Private thisRibbon             As IRibbonUI

Public Sub SetRibbonPointer(ByVal ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    ribbonPointer = ObjPtr(ribbon)
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateRibbon()
    currentRibbon.Invalidate
End Sub

Private Property Get currentRibbon() As IRibbonUI
    If thisRibbon Is Nothing Then
        Set thisRibbon = ribbonObject
    End If
    
    Set currentRibbon = thisRibbon
End Property

Private Property Get ribbonPointer() As Long
    ribbonPointer = XMLTool.GetXMLContent(ribbonXMLAddress)
End Property

Private Property Let ribbonPointer(ByVal newPointer As Long)
    XMLTool.ChangeXMLContent ribbonXMLAddress, CStr(newPointer)
End Property

Private Property Get ribbonObject() As Object
    CopyMemory ribbonObject, ribbonPointer, 4
End Property
```

The code works perfectly fine until I use the function UpdateRibbon too many times (like 6 - 9 times). After that Excel closes and after reopening Excel reports that a problem was found and wants to recover the file.

I've tested the code a few times in the immediate window to be sure and the results were consistent: after validating the ribbon 9 times Excel crashes.
I've searched the internet but couldn't find a solution for this problem.
To be clear: the ribbon functions are in an add-in and not in the same workbook as the ribbon itself.

Can anyone tell me what causes the crashes or how to prevent them? (Not invalidating the ribbon is not a solution btw :) ) Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not really supported scenario how ribbon UI can be used.

Comment: What is your end goal? Could you describe it a bit better?

Comment: The end goal is to support the user to create a report. The ribbon contains two drop-down menus. In one drop-down menu the user select if they want report A or report B. The second drop-down menu contains the formats based on the selected report. This drop-down menu has to be updated if the other report has been selected.
The functions work perfectly fine and the drop-down menu is updated correctly. However the user can only switch between report A and B 6 times before Excel crashes. Users normally don't switch that much, but I'm adding and testing functions a lot, so it gets very annoying

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev you said "This is not really supported scenario how ribbon UI can be used". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Where does these ribbon controls come from?

Comment: I made them using a tool called "Custom UI Editor for Microsoft office"
Here is a snippet from the editor:
<dropDown
 id="rxddSetReportType"
 label="Report type"
 getItemCount="getNumberOfReportTypes"
 getItemLabel="getReportTypeLabel"
 getItemID="getReportTypeID"
 getSelectedItemID="getCurrentReportTypeID"
 onAction="selectReportType_Click"/>

Comment: Why do you need to use the `CopyMemory` method?

Comment: The CopyMemory method should be used when the ribbonObject is lost. Which is every time now I think of it.

Comment: Do you get any problems without using this method in the code?

Comment: When I invalidate the ribbon in the workbook itself (without using the CopyMemory) it seems to work flawlessly. I looked more into the CopyMemory and it appears that more people experience crashes with this function. Thanks for helping me in right direction. I now have to figure out an alternative solution, but at least I know where to look / what to avoid as much as possible.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I now have a solution that works fine: I use an object in my main file as the ribbon object and pass that to UpdateRibbon function. This way I won't have to use CopyMemory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped. I've posted the answer so you could mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to avoid using the `CopyMemory` call API from the ribbon code:

```
Private Property Get ribbonObject() As Object
    CopyMemory ribbonObject, ribbonPointer, 4
End Property
```

That is not intended to work this way. Moreover, it is not supported scenario.

---

The Fluent UI is described in depth in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the length of the pointer?, i.e., instead of

```
CopyMemory ribbonObject, ribbonPointer, 4
```

try with the pointer length:

```
  CopyMemory ribbonObject, ribbonPointer, IntPtr.Size
```

Comment: I haven't fully tried that yet. The function IntPtr.Size doesn't seem to exist in VBA so I've tried StrPtr(ribbonPointer) instead. But that causes Excel to crash. While trying I also changed every Long to LongPtr, but that didn't help either.

Comment: CopyMemory most probably needs to copy 8 bytes, so a 4 byte copy is , IMO less than needed.

Comment: When I change the size from 4 to 8 and update the ribbon Excel crashes instantly

Comment: Sorry, forget my last comment, I made a mistake there. I've changed the value from 4 to 8 and it has no effect. Excel still crashes after updating 9 times.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to this discussion.
I ran into this exact problem as well!

Instead of this...

```vb
Public Sub UpdateRibbon()
    currentRibbon.Invalidate
End Sub
```

Try this...

```vb
Public Sub UpdateRibbon()
    thisRibbon.Invalidate
End Sub
```

That seemed to do it for me.

Comment: Hi Glen. Thanks for your answer. I already solved the problem by passing the ribbon as IRibbonUI. Apperently the way I coded it thisRibbon went out of scope every time. I intended to use CopyMemory as a safetynet, but it was called every time, which led to crashes. So I avoid that function now and it runs a lot better. If you use the above code  in combination with your answer you avoid the CopyMemory part as well.